# WebOS Mojo HTML5 App and Viewport

Tags: javascript, html, webos, mojo

I have an HTML App which I've already released on Android.

On WebOS, with minor tweaks, it's working fine. The only thing which does not work is the scalability of the viewport. I have 2 pages. One is scalable, and the other is not.

The scalable one never seems to work. This is what my meta looks like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=1, maximum-scale=2" />
```

I've tried others recommended by other WebOS developers but I think my problem lies elsewhere.

Here's the part where you say "Oh, that's the problem!". My app is not running on PhoneGap (don't see the point, not using any Mojo features). Also, I'm not using a **WebView**. I've just added my code on **index.html**. That code then calls another html file and everything works fine. No JS or functionality issues.

That's why I wonder, do I really need to use a **WebView**?

There's a first scene which loads a bit of html too, but that all works.

The first-assistant.js has no other code than:

```
this.controller.stageController.setWindowOrientation('left');
```

On **FirstAssistant.prototype.setup**.

**Stage Assistant** just pushes the first scene.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what way does the scalable one not work?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've stated, I think the issue may be this.  Since you want the page to be scalable, when you go to scale it the main scene tries to help you and makes itself scrollable.  Since it sounds like that's not what you want, when you push the main scene from your stage assistant make sure you set the scene scroller to disabled like so:

```
this.pushScene({name: "FirstScene", disableSceneScroller: true});
```

This might miss the mark, though, and if so please respond to the comment I left on your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, it didn't work. I didn't think it would because they are different gestures. Scrolling might make zooming a bit more annoying but when you zoom in scrolling is the only way to move around a view. I think I'll try using a WebView, like I probably should have. Still, it doesn't make sense that zooming wouldn't work on a scene.

Answer (score 0):

Yuck, just got done dealing with this myself.
Unfortunately, there is a bug in the Palm Webkit implementation.  Despite being documented in Palm's developer resources, the "user-scalable: no" viewport meta tag attribute is not supported.

On May 6th, 2010, WebOSKev said:

> We've identified this as a bug
>   (#100000 - not a typo) and will
>   address this within a future release
>   of webOS.
>
> Thanks for bringing it to our
>   attention.

See the following for more:
https://developer.palm.com/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=80&t=6448&start=0